# What is the command to push my application on github to cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Is there a command where I can push to cloud foundry without packaging my spring application as a jar? Or is the only way is to package application as a jar and push it to cloud foundry.

Comment: How would you prefer to do this?  You can point to a WAR or folder (exploded WAR / JAR) if you prefer (just set `-p` to the WAR or folder instead).  You do need to push compiled bits though, at least if you're looking to use the Java build pack.  The JBP will *not* compile / build the app for you.

Comment: Well, I know how to push after packaging it as a jar. I mean to push the whole git repo to cloud foundry. Where as if, I do an edit on my files I can refresh boot cloud foundry. To pick up the changes I've made.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an official way but maybe someone has written a CLI plugin to do that, however there would be no way to have Cloud Foundry pull it from Git, it will always have to be deployed via an "external node". Perhaps you should think about doing it with a CI pipeline of some sort, it's actually a very trivial thing to do. I wrote a blog post about it a while back... https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/products/continuous-deployment-from-github-to-pws-via-concourse